# InvalidParameterValue: Invalid Base64 stream error

Tags: typescript, nestjs, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I am sending email with attachment using aws ses service. You can see in the code, I've put the base64 code of an image and defined all other things, but when execute this code, aws-sdk throws an exception: "InvalidParameterValue: Invalid Base64 stream"

````
 const boundary = `----=_Part${Math.random().toString().substr(2)}`;

 const rawMessage = [
   `From: ${"johndoe@support.com"}`, // Can be just the email as well without <>
   `To: ${"lorem@ipsum.com"}`,
   `Subject: ${"template.SubjectPart"}`,
   `MIME-Version: 1.0`,
   `Date: ${this.formatDate(date)}`, // Will be replaced by SES
   `Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="${boundary}"`, // For sending both plaintext & html content
   // ... you can add more headers here as decribed in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-fields.html
   `\n`,
   `--${boundary}`,
   `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`,
   `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit`,
   `\n`,
   "template.TextPart",
   `--${boundary}`,
   `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`,
   `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit`,
   `\n`,
   "<h1> Thanks for reaching me out </h1>",
   `\n`,
   `--${boundary}`,
   `Content-Type: text/plain; name="${"test.jpeg"}"`,
   `Content-Description: ${"test.jpeg"}`,
   `Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="${"test.jpeg"}";`,
   `creation-date="${this.formatDate(date)}"`,
   `Content-Transfer-Encoding: ${'base64'}`,
   `\n`,
   `data:image/png;base64,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`,
   `\n`,
   `--${boundary}--`,
 ];


 const mailParams: SES.Types.SendRawEmailRequest = {
   Source: `${companyName} <${alias}>`,
   Destinations: [toEmail],
   RawMessage : {
     Data: rawMessage.join('\n'),
   },
 };
 this.sesReply
   .sendRawEmail(mailParams)
   .promise()
   .then((response) => {
     console.log(response);
     return Promise.resolve(true);
   })
   .catch(async (e) => {
     console.warn(e);
     await this.sendOfflineEmail(
       toEmail,
       message,
       alias,
       companyName,
       domain,
       sebastian,
       emailRetries
     );
   });```
````

Comment: Try `Data: Buffer.from(rawMessage.join('\n')),`

Comment: @jellycsc didn't change anything. Same error.